# Java opens a new window when I start it from mingw/msysgit, how can I stop it?

Tags: windows, java, git

When I launch anything that uses Java, i.e., command lines beginning with java, javac, jar, mvn, etc., from cmd, I see the output in the same window.  When I launch them from msysgit's bash shell on my office machine, a new cmd window appears containing the output, which then disappears afterwards so I don't get chance to read the final lines.

In contrast, on my home PC, this doesn't happen; the output appears in the shell I start Java from, whether that's msysgit or cmd.

How can I prevent this new window from opening, or can you explain why it appears?